# YouCompleteMe unavailable: dlopen... (more in description)

Tags: vim, vundle, youcompleteme

This is the full error when running vim after compiling youCompleteMe for macvim:

```
YouCompleteMe unavailable: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so, 2): Symbol not 
found: __PyCodecInfo_GetIncrementalDecoder
  Referenced from: /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
  Expected in: flat namespace

 in /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.11/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_io.so
```

I'm not finding it anywhere else online so I'm hoping you all could help me.

Comment: Seems like a version mismatch or installation error.

Comment: So strangely enough, despite the compiler not showing usage of anaconda, and despite anaconda being out of the PATH variable, removing anaconda got it working. However "remove anaconda entirely" isn't a solution, just a workaround, so I'm going to keep researching this.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error trying to install YCM on MacVim. I'm going to be honest, I'm not quite sure which command fixed it (so much for the scientific method), but it was an error with brew and the permissions on /usr/local/. Try the following commands in Terminal:

```
brew prune
sudo chown -R "$USER":admin /usr/local
brew link --overwrite python
```

I think it's the last two commands that do the trick, fixing the permissions and any errors in Python's links.

Comment: Exact same error as posted. But this work-around failed for me.

Comment: I upgraded my MacVim from Github releases (not brew), and this worked well for me: https://github.com/macvim-dev/macvim/releases

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem. Turned out I hadn't link MacVim with vim. So after I linked it with `ln -s /usr/local/bin/mvim vim`, now YCM works!